# Gazebo plugin location and documentation

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, plugin, gazebo-plugins

I have a basic question regarding gazebo plugins. The gazebo tutorial 'Moving the Robot' available at [Link](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/moving_robot) refers to the differential drive plugin coded as shown in the picture.

[image]

Where can I find more information about these plugins, more specifically:

a) Where can I find the list of all plugins?

b) For a given plugin, where can I find the details of the plugin such as filename to use (e.g: filename="gz-sim-diff-drive-system"),  name of the plugin (e.g: name="gz::sim::systems::DiffDrive">) and the other parameters of the plugin (left_joint, right_joint,wheel_separation etc.)

TIA

Comment: If you want to show code, you should not paste a screenshot, but rathert copy paste the actual text, select it, and format it as code (i.e. press Ctrl+K or click the icon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are in the Gazebo Sim github repository:

- System plugins can be found [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/gz-sim7/src/systems),
- Gui plugins are [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/gz-sim7/src/gui/plugins),
- Example worlds using these plugins are [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/gz-sim7/examples/worlds).

Documentation of each plugin is written in the header files, e.g. [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/2dbcc6c872a204e44f4dd3e3be8c44a98b04452f/src/systems/diff_drive/DiffDrive.hh#L35-L131).

The 'name' of a plugin is in the code, typically at the end. E.g. [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/2dbcc6c872a204e44f4dd3e3be8c44a98b04452f/src/systems/diff_drive/DiffDrive.cc#L682).

The 'file name' is the name of the compiled shared library. E.g. `gz-sim-diff-drive-system` for `libgz-sim-diff-drive-system.so`.

I was expecting to find the name for each system in the respective `CMakeLists.txt` file, e.g. [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/2dbcc6c872a204e44f4dd3e3be8c44a98b04452f/src/systems/diff_drive/CMakeLists.txt#L1) but it does not fully correspond. Based on [this comment](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/2dbcc6c872a204e44f4dd3e3be8c44a98b04452f/src/systems/CMakeLists.txt#L77-L79) I conclude that the `CMakeLists.txt` name always gets a prefix `gz-sim-` and a postfix `-system`.

Gui plugins on the other hand do seem to get the name from the `CMakeLists.txt` file, without suffix or postfix.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/issues/1995) about a default repository for community-written plugins, but no concrete suggestions yet. So I currently just put my plugins in a github repository (for now only a ['waste bin' plugin](https://community.gazebosim.org/t/waste-bin-system-plugin-for-gazebo-sim/2188)).

Comment: Thanks @JRTG. This is very useful.

Comment: +1 for JRTG's answer. I cannot post a comment because I'm new to the platform but really appreciate the answer, which should be included in the official Gazebo documentation in my opinion.

Comment: Please use the upvote button to support answers. It's more visible and will reward the poster with reputation.

Comment: Please open a pull request to suggest adding it to the documentation where you think it would be most helpful.