# Where can I find the list of SDF tags that can be used for a particular sensor in Gazebo Garden?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-7, gazebo-model, gazebo-sensor

From the tutorial of gazebo garden [here](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/sensors),

```
<sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
    <always_on>1</always_on>
    <update_rate>1</update_rate>
    <visualize>true</visualize>
    <topic>imu</topic>
</sensor>
```

I can see the tags that can be used in adding an IMU sensor. However, I am still not sure if the tags shown on that link are already the entire tags that can be used. Not only that, I also would like to know what tags can be used for other sensors as well e.g. Lidar sensor, camera sensor.

Where can I find the list of tags that can be used for each sensors available in Gazebo Garden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

While writing this answer, I found that the Gazebo Sim sensor parameters are read through the SDFormat library, and hence all parameters are described in the [SDFormat Specification](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.10&elem=sensor), e.g. [here](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.10&elem=sensor#sensor_imu) for the imu sensor.

**Long answer**

For Gazebo Sim system plugins, the documentation is in the header files, see [this previous answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/103884/35117) for the references.

For Gazebo Sim sensors, it seems it's a bit more elaborate:

- The sensors themselves are located in the [`gz-sensors` repository](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sensors/tree/gz-sensors7/include/gz/sensors).
- If you read through the header and source files (e.g. [ImuSensor.hh](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sensors/blob/gz-sensors7/include/gz/sensors/ImuSensor.hh) and [ImuSensor.cc](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sensors/blob/gz-sensors7/src/ImuSensor.cc)) you will find descriptions about the internal variables of the sensor,
- However, whereas the `gz-sim` system plugins typically have a `configure()` in which parameters are read from the SDF, it seems that `gz-sensors` have little logic in their `load()` call (e.g. [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sensors/blob/gz-sensors7/src/ImuSensor.cc#L118)) while the actual loading of the parameters from the SDF is deferred to the [`SDFormat` library](https://github.com/gazebosim/sdformat):

  - E.g. see the [IMU sensor header file](https://github.com/gazebosim/sdformat/blob/sdf13/include/sdf/Imu.hh) and [implementation file](https://github.com/gazebosim/sdformat/blob/sdf13/src/Imu.cc),
  - More specifically the [`load()` function](https://github.com/gazebosim/sdformat/blob/24b61531ad49420aeddb9f59c4c08b01b59e5d29/src/Imu.cc#L81) performs the read from the SDF.