# ign gazebo failing to load plugin from inside a model (gazebo fortress)

Tags: ignition-fortress

I'm trying to control an imported [pioneer model](https://app.gazebosim.org/OpenRobotics/fuel/models/Pioneer%202DX) with the old gazebo plugins changed for the ign plugins, but i keep getting the following error:

[Err] [SystemLoader.cc:78] Failed to load system plugin [ignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system.so] : couldn't find shared library.

I couldn't find an answer here or on other forums, so I'm posting this question. You can see the files used [here](https://github.com/m-almeida0/Troubleshooting/tree/main/ign%20gazebo%20plugin%20problem).

Commands used to:
run the simulation - ign gazebo test_world.sdf
publish on the cmd_vel topic - ign topic -t "/model/pioneer2dx/cmd_vel" -m ignition.msgs.Twist -p "linear: {x: 0.5}, angular: {z: 0.05}

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/moving_robot) Gazebo fortress tutorial, the plugin filename is `libignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system.so` not `ignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system.so`, that could be the reason why it is failing.

Comment: Forgot to add it to the question, but i tried with libignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system.so first and ignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system.so after seeing it on some random page i can't find again.

That being said, It's worth taking into account stupid typos as a source of problem, and considering that you can't see the cmd_vel topic on ign topic -l, maybe the issue isn't the plugin, but the topic I'm publishing on. I'll edit the question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have a look at [this previous answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/103884/35117) wrt the 'name' and 'file name' of plugins. It is worth noting that from Fortress to Garden, 'ignition' was renamed back to 'gazebo' and shorthand 'ign' became 'gz' etc. Re. `ign topic -l`: this was fixed in [Harmonic](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-transport/pull/379). As an alternative, run Gazebo with debug output: `ign gazebo -v 4 world.sdf`. Typically the plugins ouput the topic names upon load when debug output is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for showing where the documentation on plugins is easily accessible, mate.

The documentation on the DiffDrive uses two aliases: `ignition::gazebo::systems::DiffDrive` - the one I'm using - and `gz::sim::systems::DiffDrive`. When i use the latter, i get no error but the lack of response persists.

As for running on debug mode, It returns a long-ass log that will be posted on the github, but the only mention a DiffDrive topic is `[Msg] DiffDrive subscribing to twist messages on [cmd_vel]`, line 25. I tried publishing on /model/pioneer2dx/cmd_vel and on cmd_vel itself. Neither works.

Answer (score 0):

If I run the [diff_drive demo world](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/ign-gazebo6/examples/worlds/diff_drive.sdf) with debug logging enabled (`-v 4`), then among all debug output lines I find following output:

```
[Msg] DiffDrive subscribing to twist messages on [/model/vehicle_blue/cmd_vel]
[Dbg] [SystemManager.cc:74] Loaded system [gz::sim::systems::DiffDrive] for entity [8]

[Msg] DiffDrive subscribing to twist messages on [/model/vehicle_green/cmd_vel]
[Dbg] [SystemManager.cc:74] Loaded system [gz::sim::systems::DiffDrive] for entity [24]
```

This makes sense, as the example world has two diff drive plugins configured, see [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/2a9d86cc69948bcac4da58572fe2b30474a0af16/examples/worlds/diff_drive.sdf#L247-L263) and [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/2a9d86cc69948bcac4da58572fe2b30474a0af16/examples/worlds/diff_drive.sdf#L435-L450).

In your log output, I similarly find [the following](https://github.com/m-almeida0/Troubleshooting/blob/37fd517bc020f9f96e79211344378702b2f83f85/ign%20gazebo%20plugin%20problem/verbose_log.txt#L25):

```
[Msg] DiffDrive subscribing to twist messages on [cmd_vel]
```

This corresponds to the custom topic `cmd_vel` that you have set [here](https://github.com/m-almeida0/Troubleshooting/blob/37fd517bc020f9f96e79211344378702b2f83f85/ign%20gazebo%20plugin%20problem/pioneer2dx/model.sdf#L183).

I am not sure if that can work, as I'd typically expect a topic name to start with a `/`, e.g. `/cmd_vel`.

So my suggestions:

- Remove the custom topic from the sdf file,
- Check in the log output to which exact topic the plugin subscribes,

  - Normall the default topic should be: `/model/{name_of_model}/cmd_vel`,
  - Which in your case is: `/model/pioneer2dx/cmd_vel`
- Try to publish a Twist message to that topic.

  - The command to send the Twist message can be found [in the diff_drive demo world](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/2a9d86cc69948bcac4da58572fe2b30474a0af16/examples/worlds/diff_drive.sdf#L2-L17), e.g.:

  ```
  ign topic -t "/model/pioneer2dx/cmd_vel" -m ignition.msgs.Twist -p "linear: {x: 0.5}, angular: {z: 0.05}"
  ```

If this still does not work, try the demo world itself.

A further remark:

- I notice you have a field ['torque'](https://github.com/m-almeida0/Troubleshooting/blob/37fd517bc020f9f96e79211344378702b2f83f85/ign%20gazebo%20plugin%20problem/pioneer2dx/model.sdf#L179).
- The documentation of the available fields is [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/2a9d86cc69948bcac4da58572fe2b30474a0af16/src/systems/diff_drive/DiffDrive.hh#L35-L131).
- There is no field 'torque', so providing a torque will not have an effect.

**EDIT**

Try with following files. It works for me, though I am on Harmonic so could not test it for Fortress. I adapted the plugin name in the sdf according to the Fortress demo world.

The command I used is:

```
gz topic -t "/model/pioneer2dx/cmd_vel" -m gz.msgs.Twist -p "linear: {x: 1.5}, angular: {z: 0.5}"
```

which for Fortress should be:

```
ign topic -t "/model/pioneer2dx/cmd_vel" -m gz.msgs.Twist -p "linear: {x: 1.5}, angular: {z: 0.5}"
```

model.sdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <model name="pioneer2dx">
    <link name="chassis">
      <pose>0 0 0.16 0 0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
        <mass>5.67</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.07</ixx>
          <iyy>0.08</iyy>
          <izz>0.10</izz>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.445 0.277 0.17</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <collision name="castor_collision">
        <pose>-0.200 0 -0.12 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <sphere>
            <radius>0.04</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>0</mu>
              <mu2>0</mu2>
              <slip1>1.0</slip1>
              <slip2>1.0</slip2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
        </surface>
      </collision>
      <visual name="visual">
        <pose>0 0 0.04 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri>model://meshes/chassis.dae</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <visual name="castor_visual">
        <pose>-0.200 0 -0.12 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <sphere>
            <radius>0.04</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/FlatBlack</name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>
    </link>
    <link name="right_wheel">
      <pose>0.1 -.17 0.11 0 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
      <inertial>
        <mass>1.5</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.0051</ixx>
          <iyy>0.0051</iyy>
          <izz>0.0090</izz>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.11</radius>
            <length>0.05</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>100000.0</mu>
              <mu2>100000.0</mu2>
              <slip1>0.0</slip1>
              <slip2>0.0</slip2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
        </surface>
      </collision>
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.11</radius>
            <length>0.05</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/FlatBlack</name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>
    </link>
    <link name="left_wheel">
      <pose>0.1 .17 0.11 0 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
      <inertial>
        <mass>1.5</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.0051</ixx>
          <iyy>0.0051</iyy>
          <izz>0.0090</izz>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.11</radius>
            <length>0.05</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>100000.0</mu>
              <mu2>100000.0</mu2>
              <slip1>0.0</slip1>
              <slip2>0.0</slip2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
        </surface>
      </collision>
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.11</radius>
            <length>0.05</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/FlatBlack</name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>
    </link>
    <joint type="revolute" name="left_wheel_hinge">
      <pose>0 0 -0.03 0 0 0</pose>
      <child>left_wheel</child>
      <parent>chassis</parent>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
        <use_parent_model_frame>true</use_parent_model_frame>
      </axis>
    </joint>
    <joint type="revolute" name="right_wheel_hinge">
      <pose>0 0 0.03 0 0 0</pose>
      <child>right_wheel</child>
      <parent>chassis</parent>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
        <use_parent_model_frame>true</use_parent_model_frame>
      </axis>
    </joint>
    <!--plugin filename="gz-sim-diff-drive-system"
            name="gz::sim::systems::DiffDrive"-->
    <plugin
        filename="ignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system"
        name="gz::sim::systems::DiffDrive">
      <left_joint>left_wheel_hinge</left_joint>
      <right_joint>right_wheel_hinge</right_joint>
      <torque>5</torque>
    </plugin>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

test_world.sdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<sdf version="1.6">
  <world name="test_world">
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-physics-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Physics">
    </plugin>

    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-scene-broadcaster-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::SceneBroadcaster">
    </plugin>
  
    <model name="ground_plane">
      <static>true</static>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <ambient>0.9 0.9 0.9 1</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.9 0.9 0.9 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.9 0.9 0.9 1</specular>
          </material>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>

    <include>
      <uri>model.sdf</uri>
    </include>

  </world>
</sdf>
```

Comment: 'torque" was on the model downloaded from fuel, so i chose not to change it.

I had tried without the custom topic at first, and things still didn't work, but i didn't try running the world with -v 4 without the custom topic. The proper topic is present on it, but publishing on it has no effect.

The diff_drive example runs perfectly, which makes me believe that there's either some small issue with topics when models are included, or there's something wrong with that pioneer model, so I'll focus on that for now.
Thank you for your time and patience, JRTG.

Comment: I have added sdf files that work in Harmonic. "Thank you for your time and patience," you're welcome! It takes a lot of patience to learn ROS/Gazebo. ;-) But it is worth it in the end.