# Gazebo fortress ubuntu: Building from source fails

Tags: gazebo

I'm desperately trying to build gazebo from source in my ubuntu distribution, but the build process fails every time. First I tried to install harmony without any luck, but trying to install fortress isn't much better. While building fortress it always fails within the ignition-physics5 build process, leading to following error:

```
stderr: ignition-physics5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lTINYXML2_LIBRARY_/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml2.so-NOTFOUND: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [dartsim/CMakeFiles/ignition-physics5-dartsim-plugin.dir/build.make:324: lib/libignition-physics5-dartsim-plugin.so.5.3.2] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:352: dartsim/CMakeFiles/ignition-physics5-dartsim-plugin.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2

Failed   <<< ignition-physics5 [5.56s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 6 packages finished [55.3s]
  1 package failed: ignition-physics5
  1 package had stderr output: ignition-physics5
```

I already checked if tinyxml2 is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libtinyxml2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libtinyxml2-dev is already the newest version (9.0.0+dfsg-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 42 not upgraded.
```

Looks like a missing dependency for me, but following the [step by step instructions](https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/install_ubuntu_src) multiple times now, I really don't know what else to do.
Colcon graph looks fine for me.

I'm running my Ubuntu distribution in a wsl2 environment, if that's from any concern.

Any any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i deleted my ubuntu distribution and tried to install and build harmonic sources from the scratch in a fresh ubuntu distro.

This did the trick, while doing everything everything step by step from the install instructions again. Only issue is one warning about optix:

```
stderr: gz-rendering8
CMake Warning at /mnt/d/GIT_Repositories/gz-harmonic/install/share/cmake/gz-cmake3/cmake3/GzConfigureBuild.cmake:68 (message):
   CONFIGURATION WARNINGS:
   -- Skipping component [optix]: Missing dependency [OptiX].
      ^~~~~ Set SKIP_optix=true in cmake to suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:216 (gz_configure_build)
```

Is this a known warning and something to worry about?

Comment: Yes, that's a known warning. Nothing to worry about.https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-rendering/issues/281

Comment: Ok thanks, that's good news