# How to find the plugin which the sensor should use quickly?

Tags: ros2, sensors, gazebo-plugin, beginner, ignition-fortress

I'm a beginner of gazebo.And I am trying to insert sensor plugins in my SDF file.But I don't know which plugin should use in my file. And I don't know how to find the correct [filename] & [name] & related parameters of the plugin.I have searched the plugin library of the gazebo document,but there are lots of c++ code which let me confused.
For example:I want to use the camera sensor,so how can I find that:
'''《plugin
filename="ignition-gazebo-sensors-system"
name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Sensors">
<render_engine>ogre</render_engine>
</plugin》'''

Wishing for your answers.
Thanks,Li

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of example demo worlds [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/gz-sim8/examples/worlds).
For Gazebo Fortress, see the corresponding [github branch](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/ign-gazebo6/examples/worlds).

If you are just starting out with Gazebo, I suggest to use the latest version (Harmonic) instead of Fortress, especially as Fortress still uses the 'Ignition'naming, which changed to 'Gazebo Sim' due to trademark issues.

For more info wrt. plugins, name, filename etc, see [this previous answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/103884/35117).